# Debian Stretch - manage AMD gpu without aticonfig

Tags: debian, amd-graphics-card, fglrx

I recently upgraded to Debian Testing, currently Stretch. In Jessie, the cli tool to manage the fan control was

```
# aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 50"`
```

However, in Stretch, this tool was removed. Where did it go, can I get it back, or is there an equivalent to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that AMD stop supporting unix based system that's why it was removed from repositories.

More on this: [The AMD Catalyst Legacy driver - supporting the Radeon HD 2000/3000/4000 series - is not available for Debian 8 "Jessie", as upstream has not updated the driver for newer Xorg releases](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary)

and in the [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788804#5) :

> Upstream hasn't produced an update for a couple years now even though
>   the package is entirely broken: http://bugs.debian.org/726500